# How can I get back some data automatically after a POST?

Tags: php, html, ajax, json

How can I get back (to the browser) some data automatically (from server) after a POST?

1. I have a HTML form
2. I POST the form's data to a php code eg: saveRecord()
3. the php code saves the data in a mySQL DB
4. if the data contains a non 0 record ID there will be an UPDATE, if the record ID == 0 there will be an INSERT, and the php code knows (gets back from DB) the new record ID
5. (after INSTER) how can I send that new record ID back to (browser) HTML form?

If I edit an existing record (ID !=0 ), everithing is fine...

My problem is that, when I post NEW data (ID == 0) I can post it several times, and the php code each time creates a new record in the DB... But I really don't want that. I would like to send (from the server) back (to the browser) the INSERTed records ID (right in the HTML form), to prevent multiple INSERTs...

How can I do that?!

the specific CI code:

```
function update($record) {

    print_r($record);

    $id = $record['crn_id'];
    $record['crn_active'] = ( ($record['crn_active'] == 'on') ? 1 : 0 );
    array_shift($record);
    if ($id == 0) {            
        $this->db->insert('currencies', $record);
    } else {
        $this->db->where('crn_id', $id);
        $this->db->update('currencies', $record);
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: please share your code, so we can see what you are **actually** doing.

Comment: you may need to use mysqli_insert_id($connection); // to find last inserted Id..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three ways to help you on your way that can be generalized:

1. Make another column unique. If you care so much about possibly having duplicate data in your database there may be some rule to it that you can generalize in the form of a constraint.
2. Disable the submit button after it was clicked (e.g. `<input type="submit" onsubmit="this.disabled=true">`). (make sure to re-enable it if some ajax based validation fails)
3. Use a one time key generated to make sure the user did not just reload the submitted page. Have a look at [form keys](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/secure-your-forms-with-form-keys--net-4753) which can also help against CSRF and XSS attacks.

Comment: THX! the 3rd pont it's a good idea, but I don't agree the 2nd one... The user must be able to POST the form data again and again... but the code (or system) should be SMART ENOUGH to know if it's a NEW data, or is it only an UPDATE of the previously POSTed NEW data...

Comment: Agreed that the second suggestion isn't foolproof. The most common ways fools re-post though is by impatiently clicking the same button many times.

Comment: in fact I have to solv it on a different way... I have to use AJAX post insted of simple (form)post...